# Maven downloads pom but not jars

Tags: maven, gradle

I've read through the other questions with similar descriptions, but I didn't see anything that would help. I have a new project I've uploaded to Maven Central. I'm now trying to use it from another project.

I'm going to include All The Info. I think I might have a signing issue. But I've included my `pom.xml`, my original `build.gradle` (enough of it anyway), and a bunch of other things.

I have this in my `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.jplflyer</groupId>
        <artifactId>Spring-Web-JWT</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I can go to this URL and see my stuff: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/github/jplflyer/Spring-Web-JWT/1.0.0/

The original project is a Gradle project, and I have these in my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
// The normal stuff
    id 'net.thebugmc.gradle.sonatype-central-portal-publisher'  version '1.1.1'
}

centralPortal {
    pom {
        // `name = project.name`, `description = project.description` and `packaging = "jar"`
        // are applied automatically, but you can override them here
        name = 'Spring Web JWT'
        description = 'Provides boilerplate for implementing JWT Authentication'
        url = 'https://github.com/jplflyer/Spring-Web-JWT'
        licenses {
            license {
                name = 'The MIT License'
                url = 'https://opensource.org/license/mit/'
            }
        }
        developers {
            developer {
                id = 'jplflyer'
                name = 'Joseph Larson'
                email = 'jpl@showpage.org'
            }
        }
        scm {
            connection = 'scm:git:git://github.com/jplflyer/Spring-Web-JWT.git'
            url = 'https://github.com/jplflyer/Spring-Web-JWT'
        }
    }
}
```

I have signing and upload information in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties:

```
signing.keyId= VALUE
signing.password= PASSWORD
signing.secretKeyRingFile= PATH

centralPortal.username= VALUE
centralPortal.password= VALUE
```

And I have this output:

```
$ mvnw install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< org.showpage:AuthorAide >-----------------------
[INFO] Building AuthorAide 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/github/jplflyer/Spring-Web-JWT/1.0.0/Spring-Web-JWT-1.0.0.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/github/jplflyer/Spring-Web-JWT/1.0.0/Spring-Web-JWT-1.0.0.pom (2.3 kB at 8.7 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/github/jplflyer/Spring-Web-JWT/1.0.0/Spring-Web-JWT-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.002 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-18T14:21:35-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project AuthorAide: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.showpage:AuthorAide:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: io.github.jplflyer:Spring-Web-JWT:jar:1.0.0 (absent): Could not find artifact io.github.jplflyer:Spring-Web-JWT:jar:1.0.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

But I only get these contents:

```
# cd ~/.m2/repository/io/github/jplflyer/Spring-Web-JWT/1.0.0
$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jpl  staff   251 Feb 18 14:21 Spring-Web-JWT-1.0.0.jar.lastUpdated
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jpl  staff  2275 Feb 18 12:00 Spring-Web-JWT-1.0.0.pom
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jpl  staff    40 Feb 18 14:21 Spring-Web-JWT-1.0.0.pom.sha1
-rw-r--r--@ 1 jpl  staff   174 Feb 18 14:21 _remote.repositories
```

**Could This Be Signing?**

Maybe this is a signing failure? I used the `gpg` tool to upload my signing key. Maybe I'm supposed to share that somehow?

I'm so close, but not quite there. Ideas?

Comment: Based on the reference on the repo there is missing a classifier `<classifier>plain</classifier>` because the artifacts in the repository does not contain a jar without classifier...

Comment: @khmarbaise I didn't even know about classifiers. Thank you. That fixed my download.